# error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './locale' in+metronic'

Tags: laravel-mix, metronic

In the metronic theme v 8.0.24 , the following error occurs when compiling with Laravel Mix.

```
WARNING in ./public/theme/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js 22:200849-200871
```

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './locale' in 'C:\xampp1\htdocs\aseman\public\theme\assets\plugins\global'

webpack compiled with 1 warning

Comment: Did you manage to solve this please? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Proceed exactly as in the documentation.
First run inside the template.
Then run inside Laravel.
If there is a problem, ask